# White dots top corner of every photo

Tags: pentax, film-cameras

Recently got scans back and noticed a small white dot in the top corner of every photograph. The exposure otherwise seemed to be ok.

I shot it with my Pentax 67 and used Kentmere 400. It was developed and scanned at a lab.

Any ideas what could have caused this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the negatives for the same spot?

Comment: I also see some small straight lines near the white dots.  They are most obvious in the 3rd photo, but I can see them in a couple of the others